# Filter NSMutableArray on the base of filtering another NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, filtering

I have 3 `NSMutableArray`s of identical size. They are "linked" that means that for the corresponding index they have something related to each other.

```
tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", nil]

thumbnails = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"egg_benedict.jpg", @"mushroom_risotto.jpg", @"full_breakfast.jpg",nil]

prepTime = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"10min", @"15min", @"8min",nil]
```

This comes from a tutorial I'm playing on.

I'm filtering the tableData array like this:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

searchResultsData = [[tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] mutableCopy];
```

where `searchText` is the string containing the filter (for example "egg").
This works great, I mean I have the correct filtering. (`searchResultsData` is another NSMutableArray)
What I need to do is filter the other two `NSMutableArray`s on the basis of the result got from the `NSPredicate` above.

So I created other two `NSMutableArray`s called "searchResultThumbnails" and "`searchResultPrepTime`".
I'm expecting this: if I filter using the word "egg" I want the first element containing "egg" from the "`tableData`" array (in this case only one element) and the correspondent element at index in the thumbnails and preptime arrays.

So after filtering with "Egg" the result should be:

```
searchResultData = "Egg"
searchResultThumbnails = "egg_benedict.jpg"
searchResultPrepTime = "10min"
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: consider to use one array of dictionaries or – still better – of custom class objects with appropriate properties

Comment: Parallel arrays are a hold-over from the days before object-oriented programming.  They were error-prone then and no better now.  (If you **absolutely must** do it this way, take each item in `searchResultsData`, find its index in `tableData`, and use those indexes to find objects in the other main arrays to populate your search arrays...but it's still a bad idea.  :) )

Comment: Supporting @stklieme comments, Your Array of dictionary could be like ( { searchResultData = "Egg"
searchResultThumbnails = "egg_benedict.jpg"
searchResultPrepTime = "10min"}........................{ } )

Answer (score 0):

Believing "They are "linked" that means that for the corresponding index they have something related to each other." as your situation

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

searchResultsData = [[tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] mutableCopy];
NSString *searchedText = [searchResultsData objectAtIndex:0];
NSInteger index = [tableData indexOfObject:searchedText]; //if searchedText = "Egg"
NSString *thumb = [thumbnails objectAtIndex:index];
NSString *prep= [prepTime objectAtIndex:index];
```

**But this is not a better way to do this.**

**You got couple of options like 
You can use a custom Class which might have properties item, thumbnail, prepTime.**

**You can also use a Array of dictionaries similar to the following format,**

```
 array = (
          {
             searchResultData = "Egg"
             searchResultThumbnails = "egg_benedict.jpg"
             searchResultPrepTime = "10min"
          }
          {
             searchResultData = "someItem"
             searchResultThumbnails = "some.jpg"
             searchResultPrepTime = "10min"
          }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray* tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", nil];

NSArray* thumbnails = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"egg_benedict.jpg", @"mushroom_risotto.jpg", @"full_breakfast.jpg",nil];

NSArray* prepTime = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"10min", @"15min", @"8min",nil];

NSMutableArray *storedIndex = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:tableData.count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0 ; i != tableData.count ; i++) {
    [storedIndex addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
}

//Now you are going to sort tabledata.. with it we will sort storedIndexs
//suppose we will compare the strings for this time
[storedIndex sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){

NSString *lhs = [[tableData objectAtIndex:[obj1 intValue]] lowercaseString];
NSString *rhs = [[tableData objectAtIndex:[obj2 intValue]] lowercaseString];
return [lhs compare:rhs];
}];     //now storedIndex are sorted according to sorted tableData array

NSMutableArray *sortedTableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:tableData.count];
NSMutableArray *sortedThumbnail = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:tableData.count];
NSMutableArray *sortedPrepTime = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:tableData.count];

[p enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSUInteger pos = [obj intValue];
    [sortedTableData addObject:[tableData objectAtIndex:pos]];
    [sortedThumbnail addObject:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:pos]];
    [sortedPrepTime addObject:[prepTime objectAtIndex:pos]];
}];

//Now all will be correct index relation to each other as previous
```

It will work perfectly.
Happy coding. :)